# Am I using foremost (disk recovery tool) correctly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, testdisk

I have a MacBook, and I meant to do a dual boot with Ubuntu, but after I created the partitions, I clicked "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", so the partition I had created for Ubuntu was not utilized, and so I thought my whole macOS, and all of its files, were gone.  However, lately I have read that I should be able to get many of the files from before I made that mistake.

I have heard of TestDisk, but the tool "foremost" seemed better for me.  I used it to search for png files from before the disk erase, and I typed `foremost -t png`, which was supposed to search for png files from raw byte data on the hard drive, looking for standard png headers/footers/patterns/etc.

I ran the program all night, but it didn't turn up anything.  When foremost started, it printed a pipe, `|`, which I thought was the beginning of a status bar (with `||||` being about 10% or so), but no more pipes were ever printed out.

Is it possible that the program just takes forever?  There are other parameters I could specify to make it faster, but it would take me a little while to understand them, as I am not an IT specialist (I am a software developer, however).

Is it possible that this tool is designed only for Linux, so that when searching through a (formerly) mac hard disk, it's not looking for the correct patterns?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd try PhotoRec instead (from the TestDisk author, and in the testdisk package IIR), it's got nice terminal menus for picking formats to recover, and progress displays. I had no luck getting foremost to work

Comment: Welcome :) Should I make that an answer, if it worked? Doesn't really address foremost directly, but if it solves the problem better...?

Comment: @Xen2050, sure, why not?  Foremost didn't seem to be working for me, and if never worked for you, it'd probably good to know that maybe it's just an obsolete/broken program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try PhotoRec instead (from the [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) authors, it's in the testdisk package on Ubuntu/Debian), it's got nice *terminal/ascii gui* menus for picking file formats to recover, can search all or only free space, and has progress displays.

I had no luck getting foremost to work either, apparently it's still a basic command-line only program, but a quick search showed a few promising links for using foremost:

- [How to restore deleted files in Linux with Foremost](https://linuxtechlab.com/restore-deleted-files-linux-with-foremost/) - Basically just run `foremost` with the `-t [filetype]` option on a device `-I` - it's not clear if the entire device is searched (finding every file) or just free space (finding only deleted/lost files, without any other options I'd guess it finds all files.
- [Recover Deleted Files With foremost](https://www.howtoforge.com/recover-deleted-files-with-foremost) - as above, but adds an output folder option `-o`, and that foremost outputs an `audit.txt` file showing it's version, where it looked & what it found.
- [Unix & Linux Q: Recover deleted files using foremost](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207928/recover-deleted-files-using-foremost) - It's implied that foremost needs access to the device it's searching (may need to run as root/sudo), and there may be better programs for just undeleting files, like perhaps `ntfsundelete` or TestDisk.

TestDisk itself is excellent at undeleting files, if it knows the filesystem it could browse all files (deleted and regular) and copy them to another destination, perhaps with their original filenames too.

Comment: PhotoRec did the trick for me. `foremost` is stuck with `processing: stdin` for the same device.

Answer (score 1):

foremost is not *stuck* with processing: stdin. As it says, it tries to process stdin, the standard input and since you don't supply any data to stdin it will wait until an end-of-file character is printed.

You probably didn't specify the input device correctly. E.g. if you unmounted the partition that you are about to scan before running foremost then it falls back to use stdin.

Comment: Hi @blekdushi, what if the device is properly mounted and accessible, but it still stops at stdin?

Answer (score 0):

To find the device to use with foremost, try:

lsblk (if usb device) then use what you get. I got `/dev/sda1`:

```
foremost -v -q -t rar -i /dev/sda1 -o /home/myuser/Downloads/tmp/
```

Either find what is the `/dev/device` you want to recover files from.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that foremost did not have permission to read the disk.

The solution for me was running it as administrator with:

```
sudo foremost ...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).